# Getting 404 with http://www.springframework.org/schema/p

Tags: java, spring

Is there another way to get this xmlns:p?
here is my trying:

xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
   xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">
<bean id="testPNamespace" class="org.learning.exemples.PNamespaceTest"
    p:value ="10">
</bean>
```

Class:

```
package org.learning.exemples;

public class PNamespaceTest {

    private final String value;

    public PNamespaceTest(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }
}
```

IDE error message:

> Attribute p:value is not allowed here

Comment: Add the complete XML.

Comment: Improve this question, pretty unclear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have both getter and **setter** in  `org.learning.exemples.PNamespaceTest` to be able to use `p:value="somevalue"` in xml. So just add

```
public void setValue(String value) {
    this.value = value;
}
```

---

Or you could use `xmlns:c="http://www.springframework.org/schema/c"` it is a shortcut for `constructor-arg`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
   xmlns:c="http://www.springframework.org/schema/c"
   xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">
<bean id="testPNamespace" class="org.learning.exemples.PNamespaceTest"
    c:value ="10">
</bean>
```

Comment: Also I need to take out my constructor, thanks I was missileding by trying to open the url on my web browser.

Answer (score 1):

## Do not use the p: syntax

If it is only about setting up some properties for a bean, you may resort to basics and skip the *p* schema altogether. The `p:value = "10"` syntax is a shortcut to set a property

```
<property name="value" value="10" />
```

so terminate the bean header with `/>` before the property and insert the property inside the bean body, and then you can skip the `xmlns:p=". . .`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">
<bean id="testPNamespace" class="org.learning.exemples.PNamespaceTest" />
    <property name="value" value="10" />
</bean>
```